# getting error while applying a kind of filtering in temporal domain

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, video-streaming, video-processing

I used this code to detect a circle in the stream.

```
      vector<Vec3f> circles;
  /// Apply the Hough Transform to find the circles
   HoughCircles( src_gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, src_gray.rows/8, 200, 100, 0, 0 );
 for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
 {
      Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
      Vector.push_back(std::make_pair(center.x,center.y)); 
      int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
      // circle center
      circle( src, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
      // circle outline
      circle( src, center, radius  Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );
   }
```

There is just one circle in the image. so, what I have in the pair-value vector is coordinate of the center point. so, Vector has just one pair value!(Probabely)

Now I want to apply a kind of filtering into this point in sequence of frames.somethig like Bilateral Filte
but I get memory allocation error!!(while I am not using pointer in this case)

```
cv::bilateralFilter ( Vector , Output, 8, 8*2, 8/2 );
```

This is what I have in the header file:

```
std::vector< std::pair< std::vector<int>, std::vector<int> > > Vector;
std::vector< std::pair< std::vector<int>, std::vector<int> > > Output;
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
std::vector< std::pair< std::vector<int>, std::vector<int> > > Vector;
```

makes "Vector" a vector of pairs of vectors of ints.  You don't need the things in the pair to be vectors, that doesn't make sense.

Better:

```
std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > CenterPoints;
```

Next issue, "Now I want to apply a kind of filtering into this point in sequence of frames" - okay, but bilateral filter in OpenCV works on images, not on sequences of points or anything like that.  I think you want to smooth out a curve described by the points, bilateral filter can't do that for you.

Anyway, this code:

```
cv::bilateralFilter ( Vector , Output, 8, 8*2, 8/2 );
```

fails because `bilateralFilter()` expects `Mat` for the first and second argument (ie: images).

Check out the sample code here:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html

```
Mat src; Mat dst;
bilateralFilter ( src, dst, i, i*2, i/2 );
```

*EDIT*

If I understand the problem, you are finding a circle in successive frames and then trying to find a smooth path of the movement of the center of the circle?  You need to define what is "smooth".  For example, you could try to fit splines to the movement, or do some kind of lowpass filter, or ...

Simplest solution: for point N along the path, replace with average of positions of points N-K to N+K (you can use weighted average, to produce temporal FIR filter with desired characteristics; simple average is a basic lowpass filter).

To create intermediate points, use splines.  There are no builtin splines in OpenCV; but there are plenty of libraries.  See: [Cubic Spline : Start/End Segment interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043064/cubic-spline-start-end-segment-interpolation)

This method is useful for smoothing, but only on (closed) contours: [OpenCV, how to use arrays of points for smoothing and sampling contours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925777/opencv-how-to-use-arrays-of-points-for-smoothing-and-sampling-contours)

Comment: Thanks. I thought that it does not matter that I am in spatial domain or temporal! if I apply a kind of filtering in spatial domain it would be spatial filtering and if I apply it into a temporal domain it would be temporal filtering!

Comment: @aa: It is just image filtering in OpenCV, sorry, there is no "domain", most filters just work on one image.  Please see updated answer for some more suggestions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me to explain what I am trying to do exactly. what I am doind is trying to reduce motion blur! To do that, I am using a fast moving ball. I could detect the ball(as a circle), then I tried to find its middle point coordinate. Now, what I was  trying to do was trying to use Bilateral filter(it smooths the image but with preserving edges) in sequence of frames.I wanted to apply it on that center point. I think the whole idea is wrong.

Comment: @aa: Okay. I think you may want to post a new question for that, please include an example image, and some idea of what you want the output to be.  Also please remember to up-vote and accept this answer if it was helpful.  You wanted to know why you get an error, well I did answer that :)

Comment: Just let me know, what is the benefit of using contour to noise reduction in this case? thanks in advance.

Comment: @aa: Smoothing the path consisting of the center points mainly helps reduce any errors with estimating each individual center point. If motion is relatively smooth, then averaging N frames reduces error by sqrt(N).  The question I linked to about contours is an effective way of smoothing, but really only works on loops or closed paths, it won't work here.